# Django - setup path to celerybeat scheduler in supervisor

Tags: django, supervisord, celerybeat

In my django settings.py file I have the following code for the celerybeat scheduler

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'call-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.update_value',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=30),
    },
}
```

How would I set the path to my CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE in my supervisord.conf file, which looks like this

```
[program:celerybeat]
command=celery beat -A RPF1 --schedule path/to/celerybeat/schedule --loglevel=INFO
```

Any information will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Good question, same concerns here. Did you get something?

Answer (score 0):

Drop off the `--schedule` argument.  It's unnecessary.  Celery will pick up the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE from the Django environment and use that.

Comment: I'm with a similar problem, and the celery isn't picking the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE, what can I do?